# How can I fake STDIN in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I am unit testing a component that requires user input. How do I tell [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::More) to use some input that I predefined so that I don't need to enter it manually?

This is what I have now:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use TestClass;

    *STDIN = "1\n";
    foreach my $file (@files)
    {

#this constructor asks for user input if it cannot find the file (1 is ignore);
    my $test = TestClass->new( file=> @files );

    isa_ok( $test, 'TestClass');
    }


done_testing;
```

This code  does press enter but the function is retrieving 0 not 1;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following minimal script seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package TestClass;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return unless <STDIN> eq "1\n";
    bless {} => $class;
}

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 1;

{
    open my $stdin, '<', \ "1\n"
        or die "Cannot open STDIN to read from string: $!";
    local *STDIN = $stdin;
    my $test = TestClass->new;
    isa_ok( $test, 'TestClass');
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t
1..1
ok 1 - The object isa TestClass
```

Answer (score 17):

If the program reads from `STDIN`, then just set `STDIN` to be the open filehandle you want it to be:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

*STDIN = *DATA;

my @a = <STDIN>;

is_deeply \@a, ["foo\n", "bar\n", "baz\n"], "can read from the DATA section";

my $fakefile = "1\n2\n3\n";

open my $fh, "<", \$fakefile
    or die "could not open fake file: $!";

*STDIN = $fh;

my @b = <STDIN>;

is_deeply \@b, ["1\n", "2\n", "3\n"], "can read from a fake file";

done_testing; 

__DATA__;
foo
bar
baz
```

You may want to read more about [typeglobs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) in [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and more about turning strings into fake files in the documentation for [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) (look for "Since v5.8.0, perl has built using PerlIO by default.") in [`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).

Comment: I just need to send in a 1\n in STDIN; This doesn't seem to work. *STDIN = "1\n";

Comment: You must assign an open filehandle to the `*STDIN` typeglob.  `"1\n"` is a string, not an open filehandle.  Take a look at the second part of the example (the part that starts with `my $fakefile`) for a way of creating an open filehandle out of a string.

Comment: @Chas.Owens Impressive answer.  I've localised the changes to STDIN.