# perl debugger treats STDIN as a debugger commands not as STDIN

Tags: perl, debugging, input, stdin

In my perl script I am reading user input via following construction:

```
# READ INPUT IN TO THE ARRAY, LINE BY LINE AND REMOVE SLASHES /, BLANK CHARACTERS, EMPTY LINES, AND NEWLINES
while (<>) { 
    $_ =~ s/\\//g;            # Remove slash /
    $_ =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;     # Remove heading and trailing white spaces
    $_ =~ s/^\s*$//g;         # Remove white spaces
    $_ =~ s/\r|\n//g;         # Remove CR and NL
    if ($_ !~ /^\s*$/ &&
        $_ !~ /:/     &&
        ($_ =~ /^[^=#]+=[^=#]+$/ || $_ =~ /^#+$/)){
        push @raw_admin_input, split "\n", $_; 
    }
}
```

So when I run the script I am able to paste (or type) multi-line line (enter separated) string then press enter again and hit `ctrl+d` to signalize the end of user input and it works.

Now I need to debug this script

```
main::(stdin.pl:177):        while (<>) { # READ INPUT IN TO THE ARRAY, LINE BY LINE AND REMOVE SLASHES /, BLANK CHARACTERS, EMPTY LINES, AND NEWLINES
  DB<4> s
input1
main::(skript12.pl:179):            $_ =~ s/\\//g;            # Remove slash /
  DB<4> input2

  DB<5> input3

  DB<6> #############

  DB<7> sdasda=asdasd
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at (eval 13)[/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/perl5db.pl:732] line 2, at EOF
```

The problem is that perl debugger recognizes this as a commands for debugger and not as a input from STDIN. I am pretty sure that this worked before and I am not aware that I've changed mentioned STDIN reading process.
I have also found that [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265790/how-to-fake-input-to-perls-diamond-operator) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213986/how-can-i-fake-stdin-in-perl) several ways of faking STDIN, but unfortunately I am a little bit confused with their syntax and do not know how to use them.

Comment: Feed your script from a file instead of from the keyboard.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to do this?

Comment: `perl -d myprog.pl < mystdin.txt`  or `perl -d myprog.pl myargv1.txt myargv2.txt` are the 1st two to come to mind....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Perl Debugger will take input from the Terminal.  If the program you are debugging is reading STDIN *and* your program had inherited the Terminal as it's STDIN, then you will be in the situation you are in.

You have three choices that allow you to keep reading from `<>`:

- redirect STDIN from another source: `perl -d myprog.pl < mystdin.txt` or `program_that_generates_usefull_input | perl -d myprog.pl`
- Take advantage of the fact that `<>` reads from STDIN *or* files named in ARGV:  `perl -d myprog.pl myargv1.txt myargv2.txt`
- Pay *very* close attention to which program is asking for input.

  In your example above, you `s`tep through the `while` line requesting input;  You enter the text `input1` into the program being debugged; then while the debugger is asking what to do about the 1st substitution line, you ignore the debugger hoping that the paused program might currently be accepting more text.

Comment: Any idea why this used to work? In the past I've just pasted the input as it is in question and it worked, now it doesn't and I don't know why. Also what if the perl script expect input multiple times, how to handle this problem?

Comment: Edit made to address your concerns.  Also note:  Text files containing input may be longer than one line.